# How can I get iPad's to close Bootstrap Tooltip manually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am at my wits end trying to fix this! Using Bootstrap Tooltips, I just cannot get a cross browser/device solution for closing the tooltips.

```
$('.tooltiplink').tooltip({ 
    container: 'body',
    trigger: 'hover focus',
    html: true,
    title: function() {
        divID = $(this).attr("id");
        divID = divID + "_div";
        return $("#" + divID).html();
    }
  });
```

You'll notice I'm using hover and focus as my triggers. This works perfectly for desktop browsers and chrome mobile phones. But the tooltips do not close on iPad Chrome OR Safari. All you can do is either click another tooltip or leave it open until you navigate off the page.

To take matters into my own hands I tried to bind an event to the clicking of the tooltip itself but it just will not have it!

```
$('.tooltip').bind("click tap", function(){
   $('.tooltip').css("display", "none")
});
```

I've tried click, tap, touch, touchstart. Nothing works. I just don't understand!

Interestingly, if you use trigger: 'click' the behaviour improves on iPads in that if you click the elemenet that launches the tooltip, the tooltip closes. But it's fiddly and not perfect. I want the user to be able to actually click the tooltip that pops up to close it. Or even better.... clicking anywhere off of it to close it.

Comment: Someone filed a bug for this problem here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/3417

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a common bug. It was filed here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/3417

A possible solution (from the many on that post):

```
$(function () {
    $("tip").tooltip({
        placement: 'right'
        //Need to have this click check since the tooltip will not close on mobile
    }).click(function(e) {
        $(this).tooltip('toggle');
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried that solution above but it's not cross device/browser. That fixes it (sufficiently) on the iPad, but now Chrome/Android is requiring you first focus on an element (i.e. a link), then clicking it to open the tooltip. So to the average user it looks broken! As soon as you start using "click" it solves the iPad issue, but creates new ones on the other devices. Can't believe it!

Comment: I feel your pains, I'm developing a big app in phonegap. The amount of workarounds and documentations I've been reading over the last months is crazy... From one hurdle onto the next! Sorry I can't help you any further with this problem.

Comment: It's very annoying. I even tried a setInterval to hide the element after a few seconds as a test and that didn't work. Total garbage!

Answer (score 0):

Although not ideal, I was able to set the tooltips to close after a set interval like so:

```
$('.tooltip').on('shown.bs.tooltip', function (e) {
    var trg = e.target
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(trg).tooltip('hide');
    }, 3000);
});
```